# Sudden TS "Errors" Throughout React App - Everything Works Though?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

I created a web app some months ago using React JSX for the client and Node/Express for the server.

My file extensions are .jsx as you can see here:

[image]

Everything worked fine as I was developing and even after deploying it to Heroku. I've only came back to it recently as Heroku ended their free dynos which is when all of these random errors plagued my project.

Upon opening my project for the first time in a month or two, almost every JSX file has something underlined in red despite having changed nothing within the project itself.

[image]
[image: Random red underlines everywhere]

The only reason the other files in the first image aren't red is simply because I haven't re-opened them, but they all have issues suddenly as well. As I said, there was no problem when I was initially developing on this project and in-fact there's still no problem when I run the project locally or re-deploy to Heroku...

Why would I be getting so many red underlines in my IDE when the execution is working, my language is set to React JSX and everything is as it was when I wasn't getting these underlines? Not to mention, why am I not getting errors in the terminal but it's underlining all these things? [image]

Thank you

EDIT: Here is my package.json

[image]

EDIT 2:

I have also tried downgrading from React 18 back to 17, as apparently there is a breaking change per [this Github thread(s)](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/59765)

EDIT 3: Narrowing in on the issue (whatever is it)

Here is two instances of VS Code opened, the left with an earlier version of the project before I refactored some things for Heroku (took the content of 'Server' dir out and put into the root). It was working after this for me a month or two ago so I'm not sure why that would be an issue either

[image]

---

Comment: check if type checking is enabled for js files in your vs code config. you shouldn't be getting type errors in js files otherwise

Comment: I found 'JS/TS > Implicit Project Config: Check JS' which was disabled (unchecked). I checked it to enable and restarted VS Code but still have the same issues. Was this the option you were referring to? Thank you for the reply, btw.

Comment: yeah, that's what I was referring to. not sure why vscode is checking types if it's disabled

Comment: I have the earlier version of the exact same project with some seemingly arbitrary changes such as my server file hierarchy and whatnot and that works just fine... I'm so confused it's painful.

Answer (score 0):

This was all due to the fact that I pulled out the contents of my Server directory and put it into the root:

This (working)

[image]

vs this (not working)

[image]

It never threw these errors before so something else is clearly going on but at least I figured out what was causing the issue in the first place.

If anyone could elaborate on why this is happening now as opposed to before, or at all, that would be much appreciated.